# Is it bad practice to use PHP to manipulate css classes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

A php loop get items from db and displays them in rows, 
I want the odd (1,3,5,7..) to have a specific css rotation transform. the same for the even rows.  I thought in creating the 2 classes with the desired transforms, then add then by creating a variable in php and passing the name of the class for each case as a string. Then the html smth like:

```
<div class=box "<?php echo $trans_class;?>">
```

Should I accomplish this using javascript, or php is fine?

Comment: Well for one thing, you need to include `box` inside those double quotes

Comment: Secondly, what about using a css selector to only apply the rule to odd rows? Look for the `nth-child ()` selector. You'd want `nth-child (2n+1)`

Comment: WordPress does it all the time so probably should not be bad practice, to answer that part of the question.

Comment: nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even) work too in response to^^

Comment: @ilia the more you know

Comment: Since you seem to be looking for an opinion, I will give you mine. I think it's fine if you're using PHP to create CSS on an external page. You should, however, avoid doing anything unnecessary. Inline styling, on the other hand, is a bad practice.

Comment: These two recent discussions showed three ways of doing it effectively http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714062/how-can-i-make-this-php-lines-shorter/33714159#33714159     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737090/change-color-of-output-php - with due respect to PHPglue's comment regarding inline css.

Comment: Using nth-child depends on which browsers you want to support - if you still support ie8 you may find you want something different like a different class for each state which you control with basic css in your stylesheet as you are doing.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to get your ODD and EVEN css classes.

Example:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {background: green}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: red}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

But to answer your question, no this is not bad practice. If you need to alter your HTML, you have to.